# .animate() and .remove() not playing well together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, appendto

I am trying to dismiss a notification panel that I previously appended to the body.

```
$('#notify-panel').animate({top: -250},{duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'});
```

This, by itself, works well but my goal is to move the div object so I added a .remove() statement to remove it after the animation is complete.

```
$('#notify-panel').animate({top: -250},{duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'});
$('#notify-panel').remove();
```

When I run this, the panel is removed from the body but the animate doesn't get executed, the layer is gone.  So I added the .remove() as part of a callback.

```
$('#notify-panel').animate({top: -250},{duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInOutBack'}, {callback: function(){ $(this).remove(); }});
```

This netted be the same as the previous step where the layer was removed by never animated.  So my question, if I want to animate a div layer then remove it, how would I go about doing that.  Apparently, I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The examples on the jquery-ui page do a good job demoing all this stuff... What is it your doing that those examples can't solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could have been solved by [reading the manual](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Use one of these:

```
$('#notify-panel').animate({
    top: -250
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutBack',
    complete: function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$('#notify-panel').animate({
    top: -250
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
}, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, you're missing the quotes around the value and the px.

I would write it like this:

```
$('#notify-panel').animate({
    top: '-250px'
}, {
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
}, 1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: `px` is not necessary.

Comment: You are mixing the both way of writing `.animate()`, are you sure it work?